# How to interact with Java3D elements using mouse?

Tags: java, java-3d

I want the user to be able to change the length of a cylinder by clicking-and-dragging his mouse. How should I start on this ? Any form of help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example code [here](http://www.java3d.org/selection.html). The basic idea is:

- Use mousePressed() listener to detect a mouse press.
- Use Java3D picking API to detect if mouse press intersected shape.
- Use mouseDragged() listener to detect amount of change and update your shape accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I wanted.